# cin.getline() crashes the program

Tags: c++, crash, getline

I'm fairly new to using C++ so I am not entirely sure what is going wrong with my program. Every time I run it it crashes right after a cin.getline() and I have asked elsewhere but there doesn't seem to be an obvious reason as to why it wont work. The code is meant to read user input and store it in a linked list, and then search for or remove entries in the list.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

struct node{
       char name[20];
       char age[4];
       node *next;
};

class personList{
      public:
             void add_person(char name[20], char age[4]);
             void remove_person(char name[20]);
             node *search_people(char name[20]);

      protected:
                void add_node(char name[20], char age[4]);
                void remove_node(char name[20]);
                node *search_nodes(char name[20]);
                node *root;
                node *position;        
};

void personList::add_person(char name[20], char age[4]){
     add_node(name, age);
}

void personList::add_node(char name[20], char age[4]){
     if (position == NULL)
     {
                 root = new node;
                 strcpy(root->name, name);
                 strcpy(root->age, age);
                 root->next = NULL;
                 position = root;
     }
     else
     {
                position->next = new node;
                position = position->next;
                strcpy(position->name, name);
                strcpy(position->age, age);
                position->next = NULL;
     }
}

void personList::remove_person(char name[20]){
     remove_node(name);
}

void personList::remove_node(char name[20]){
     node *targ;
     targ = search_nodes(name);
     if (targ != NULL)
     {
              delete targ;
     }
}

node *personList::search_people(char name[20]){
     position = root;
     return search_nodes(name);
}

node *personList::search_nodes(char name[20]){
    while(strcmp(position->name, name) !=0 && position->next != NULL)
    {
                          position = position->next;
    }
    if (strcmp(position->name, name) == 0)
    {
                        return position;
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;    
    }
}

int main(){
    personList database;
    int inp = 1;
    char name[20];
    char age[4];
    node *search_result;
    while (inp != 4)
    {
          cout << "list of commands:\n1. add person\n2. remove person\n3.search for person\n4. exit\n> ";
          cin.get() >> inp;
          switch (inp)
          {
                 case 1:
                      cout << "input the name and age of the person you wish to add:\n";
                      cin.getline(name, 20, '\n');
                      strcat(name, "\n");
                      cin.getline(age, 4, '\n');
                      strcat(age, "\n");
                      database.add_person(name, age);
                 case 2:
                      cout << "input the name of the person you wish to remove:\n";
                      cin.getline(name, 20, '\n');
                      database.remove_person(name);
                 case 3:
                      cout << "input the name of the person you wish to search for:\n";
                      cin.getline(name, 20, '\n');
                      search_result=database.search_people(name);
                      if (search_result == NULL)
                      {
                                        cout << "the person you searched for does not exist in this database\n";
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          cout << name << " is in the database as being " << search_result->age << " years old";
                      }
                 case 4:
                      break;
                 default:
                         cout << "bad input, please enter a number";
          }
    }      
}
```

As far as i can see from when I run it, it is the first cin.getline() in the first case at the bottom. As soon as I hit the return key the program crashes.

```
         case 1:
              cout << "input the name and age of the person you wish to add:\n";
              cin.getline(name, 20, '\n'); //this line causes the crash
              strcat(name, "\n");          //as far as I understand
              cin.getline(age, 4, '\n');
              strcat(age, "\n");
              database.add_person(name, age);
```

Also general pointers on things im doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: Use `std::string`. While you're at it, use smart pointers for the nodes. In C++, manual resource management is frowned upon.

Comment: Can you give a sample input for which the program crashes? Do you get any messages from the console when the program crashes?

Comment: You don't need the 3rd parameter in `cin.getline()`. The newline character is the default delimiter when you call getline with only two parameters. Also, as a general practice, `cin.getline(line, sizeof(line))` is both more expressive and will continue to work even if you change the number of characters allocated to `line` in a future version.

Comment: +1 I don't see why people vote this down. This is certainly ugly C++, but it is a valid beginner's question.

Comment: thanks for all the responses...
the issue happens whatever value i have entered, and its not because the input is too big because was only testing values (names) around five or six bytes in length. it just crashes as soon as i hit the enter key, no matter what i put in.

Comment: also there is no feedback from the console or anything, in fact the console window itself just crashes and i get the standard "program is not responding" from windows, and i've looked for solutions but none of them seem to work

Comment: i dont see why this has been marked as off topic...
'problem statement: the program crashes when getline is run
desired behaviour: it doesnt sodding crash when it is run'

Answer (score 2):

This is the important part of your code:

```
char name[20];
//...
cin.getline(name, 20, '\n');
strcat(name, "\n");
```

after the `cin.getline` name can contain 20 characters including the terminating null character. So you can't just add another `"\n"` to it because the buffersize is just 20, not 21.

Besides that, if your program reaches

```
database.add_person(name, age);
```

Something else goes wrong; you call add_node, which starts like this:

```
void personList::add_node(char name[20], char age[4]){
    if (position == NULL)
```

Bug `position` is never initialized, `personList` does not even have a constructor, so it will probably not be null, but also not valid.

Comment: i added that because i thought maybe the string not having the newline on the end in some cases might be causing the issue further down the line but it had no effect (so i guess i should take it out...)

Comment: @xenomote I added another issue which will fail too if the input is not too big.

Answer (score 1):

Besides what has already said about fixing the bug in the current design:

Missing that stream reading can also be done using std::string as a target, which widely frees the user from char pointer voodoo, is a common beginner's oversight.

There're not just

```
// http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline
std::istream::getline(char*, /*[...]*/)
```

but you can also use

```
// [...]
#include <string>
// [...]
// given
// std::string s
// std::istream is
// somewhere
//
// http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline
std::getline(is, s);
```

which is found in `<string>`. 
If one would be afraid of any overhead caused by buffer re-allocation one can use `s.reserve(N)` once before the stream read with a reasonable value for N.